# How can I return a string representation of a Python class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For a Python programming excercise, I need to create a class Graph with attributes Nodes and Edges. Both these attributes are lists. The list of edges is a list of tuples, where both elements of the tuple are elements of the set of the list of nodes. For example, if g is a Graph, then a valid population of g would be:
g.nodes = [1,2,3,4] and
g.edges = [(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,1)]

I have to create a method called add_node(self, node) that adds a node to the list of nodes and a method called add_edge(self, edge) that adds an edge to the list of edges provided that the edge is a tuple and both elements of the tuple are in the list of nodes. add_edge returns True if
the edge was added and False otherwise.

I wrote the following code:

```
class Graph:
def __init__(self):
    self.nodes = []
    self.edges = []
    
def add_node(self, node):
    self.nodes.append(node)
            
def add_edge(self, edge):
 if not isinstance(edge, tuple):
     return False
 
 for i in edge:
     if not i in self.nodes:
         return False
 else:
     self.edges.append(edge)
 return True
```

Now I have to return a string representation of the class 'Graph', that looks like this ‘(,)’. How can I do this?

Comment: What behavior do you want the method to exhibit if the edge being added is not a tuple or is not a member of the self.nodes

Comment: I want it to return True if the edge was added and False otherwise.

Comment: What issues are you having returning either one?

Comment: I do not know how to add the method that adds an edge under the constraint that the edge is a tuple and that elements of tuple are in the list of nodes

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? Have you broken down the problem at all, tried anything, etc.? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Clearly you need a conditional statement that tests for a tuple and also determines if tuple values are in self.nodes.  For the tuple test review isinstance() function, to determine if the edge value is already a node, check out List methods.  Once you have tried these ideas, update your post.

Comment: I have updated my code, but I have not been able to get the correct output.

Comment: I have solved my problem. But now I have to return a string representation, but I do not know how to do this. Can somebody help me out?

Comment: If one of the answers provided resolved your question, please mark the question answered

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is :

1. define a `__str__` method on your class. The challenge is that Python has no idea of how you want your class to be represented. The `__str__(self)` should return a string that represents that instance of your class. Ideally it should be a human friendly representation.
2. once the `__str__` method is define, you can simply print an instance, and it will automatically call the `__str__` method and display the string. You could also call the `str` function on an instance to get this string.

Comment: I need to use 'to_string(self)' as method. When I use that I don't receive an output. def to_string(self):
        return f"(<self.nodes>),(<self.edges>)"

Comment: it should be `return f'{self.nodes} {self.edges}'` - the angle brackets might be what confuses it.

Comment: I am not sure why you are being taught to use to_string(self) though - that is more like Java than Python - but hey ho.

Comment: How do you want your graph representation to look?    Do you want to just list the nodes, or do you want to list the edges?  Do you want the list to be ordered in any special way?

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your add_edge method as follows:

```
def add_edge(self, edge):
    if isinstance(edge, tuple) and edge[0] in self.nodes and edge[1] in self.nodes:
        self.edges.append(edge)
        return True
    return False
```